# Directus : How to create a many-to-many relationship to the same collection properly

Tags: php, relationship, directus, headless-cms

I created a **topics** collection.
And I want to create a **many-to-many** relationship to the same collection.
The column name is **related_topics**.

I followed the documentation so I created a **many-to-many** relation for this column and a junction table which will relate *topic.id* to *topic_related.topic_id1* and from the other side *topic.id* to *topic_related.topic_id2*.

For a Topic (A) I can select the Topic (B).

However if I open (B) I don't see any related topic there.

I expect to see (A).

Am I doing something wrong ?

Thanks for your time !

EDIT1 :

Related Topic
[image]

On the page of topic A I will select B as related article :
[image]

I expect to find this relation on the page of topic B also but I found this :
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There seems to be a discrepancy in the description as I can understand, but, is this what you are trying to do:

```
topics.related_topics => junction collection => topics.id
```

If so, you have created a unidirectional relation from parent to one or more children on the field **related_topics**, in that you are asking what topics are related to this item.

If you want to see to what parents a child item is related, create another **M2M Interface** using the same junction collection, but flip the fields from the previous M2M Interface settings and now you can see it the other way automatically.

You should then be doing:

```
topics.id => junction collection => topics.related_topics
```

The logic of M2M is unidirectional: parent to many children as it extends O2M: https://docs.directus.io/guides/interfaces.html#core-interfaces

You can, however, extend the **M2M Interface** if you want to make it bidirectional by following, intermediate understanding of Vue.js is recommended: https://docs.directus.io/extensions/interfaces.html

You would need to update the input.vue in: https://github.com/directus/app/tree/master/src/interfaces/many-to-many